# set class for empty option in dropdown list cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I'm working on a dynamic dropdown list where I can set an empty option which is selected by default. I want to set text-palceholder class for default selected option.

I want to generate options like this,

```
<select name="category" class="form-control-chosen form-control">
   <option class="text-placeholder" value="">all category</option>
   <option value="">Customer Service</option>
   <option value="">Designer</option>
   <option value="">Developer</option>
   <option value="">Finance</option>
   <option value="">Human Resource</option>
   <option value="">Information Technology</option>
   <option value="">Marketing</option>
   <option value="">Others</option>
   <option value="">Sales</option>
</select>
```

Now here I want to set class for first option (or empty option).
I am doing like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('location',array(
      'class' => 'form-control-chosen form-control',
      'options'=>$categories,
      'div' => false,
      'label' => false,
   ));
?>
```

I want to add empty option which is selected by default and stay disabled (as placeholder).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('location', array(
      'class' => 'form-control-chosen form-control',
      'options' => $categories,
      'div' => false,
      'label' => false,
      'placeholder' => 'all categories'
   ));  
?>
```

You can also add a class with jquery:

```
$("select option:first-child").addClass("text-placeholder");
```

Here you can read about the .addClass:
https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: yeah, i also tried to add class using jquery but not working.

Comment: can you suggest something else ?

Comment: Did you place the jquery code at the bottom of your file?

Comment: You need to add "-child" after the "first". I updated my answer.

Comment: So the solution is: $("select option:first-child").addClass("text-placeholder");

Comment: Did it work? If so wil you mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: Not i did not work .. not adding the class for child.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Well it should work, it works fine when I try it.

Comment: Let's continue this conversation in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107173/class-jquery

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
      echo $this->Form->input('location',array(
      'class' => 'form-control-chosen form-control',
      'options'=>$categories,
      'div' => false,
      'label' => false,
      'empty' => 'Placeholder text'    )); 
 ?>
```

Comment: i can add empty option which is selected by default i want that option to be disabled so user can not select this option.

Comment: you can add 'disabled'=>'disabled'